# Create a has_many through record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a user a movie and a watchlist model in my Ruby project.

movie.rb:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :watchlists
  has_many :users, through: :watchlists
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :watchlists
  has_many :movies, through: :watchlists
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :recoverable,
         :rememberable,
         :trackable,
         :validatable,
         # :confirmable,
         :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

watchlist.rb

```
class Watchlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And this is the MoviesController:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /movies
  def create
    if Movie.exists?(title: movie_params[:title])
      render json: { body: 'Movie already exists', status: 400 }
    else

      @movie = Movie.create!(movie_params)
      render json: { body: @movie, status: 200 }
    end

  end

  def movie_params
    # whitelist params
    params.permit(:title, :created_by, :id)
  end

end
```

Currently I only store the movie in the movie table. How do I create a record in the watchlist that has a movie id and a user id?

Answer (score 0):

If you <s>are using *Devise*</s> have `current_user`, just do

```
@movie = current_user.movies.create!(movie_params)
```

instead of

```
@movie = Movie.create!(movie_params)
```

If you <s>are not using *Devise*</s> don't have `current_user`, fetch the logged in user, say `@user` and do

```
@movie = @user.movies.create!(movie_params)
```

Comment: Meh. I'm using https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth but `current_user` is undefined in the movies_controller. And this is in the log > `(undefined method `movies' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Then fetch the logged in user record as I said in second approach

Comment: Yea okay, but shouldn't I be able to use current_user with the devise_token_auth gem?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma `current_user` should be available. Check if the user is signed in or it will return `nil`

Comment: It looks like that back-end validation is ... out of the window. I've cloned the example project (https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token-example) but that's having the same issue. Current_user is not available. So I guess I have to send the user data from the front-end since it's available there.